# How to retrieve URL path one level below in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, routes

I have a route, for example  `/posts/6`, I want at this route to make a button which will redirect me back to url path one level below, in that case, to `/posts/`. I didn't found a method of `Request` or `Route` class in BLADE, that will solve that issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
<a href="{{ url("/posts/") }}" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">Back</a>
```

Or if you wanna make it parametrized

```
<a href="{{ url($param) }}" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">Back</a>
```

---

*EDIT*

Or more **generic**

```
@php
   //get the full url
   $url = url()->full();
   //get the position of the last "/"
   $pos = strrpos($url,"/");
   //cut the string from 0 to the correct position
   $newUrl = substr($url,0,$pos); 
@endphp

<a href="{{ $newUrl }}" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">Back</a>
```

Comment: Yep, that seems to be so elementary, with "hardcoded" routes in buttons, that's why I was trying to find a dynamic way of doing it. 
A probable solution may be retrieving `Route::path()` and then with PHP `explode` on `/` to delete last url partials, but that's ugly.
Anyway, thanks for your answer.

Comment: @priMo-ex3m, I've updated my answer with a generic case

Comment: Yep, it looks similar to my possible solution, but that's kind of ugly. So, I'll use at first page a button with `URL::previous()` route, and at the second one a `{{route('posts.index')}}`.

Comment: It looks correct for your purpose. If you need it in different layouts you can create a "part" layout and include it. e.g. @include("back.button") or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

you should try this:

```
<a href="{{ url()->previous() }}" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">Back</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for advice, I know that method, but it's not enough for my case.
For example, I have a dashboard, I'm going to `/manage/posts`, there I have a back button that works exactly as you said, next, I had at the same page all my posts, so if i'm going now to `/manage/posts/6`, here I have the second back button, and if i click it, it returns me to `/manage/posts/`, but if I'm clicking now at that first back button, it returns me at `/manage/posts/6` instead of `/manage/posts/`. So, it goes in an infinite loop :).
That's why I'm trying to find a solution of removing one level from `path`

Answer (score 0):

There are pretty many ways to do this . But it's up tp what you want.

1) . The first *dumb way* is to use static route  `<a href="{{ route('posts')}}>Back</a>` .
Although i believe it s a good way if we are talking about a specific case

2)If you have always a pattern like  `resource/resourceId` you can just  get the current url and remove the last part (via **explode()** or any other function) .

Example

`<a href="{{ returnMyResourceRouteName(url()->current() ) }}>Back</a>` .

where the `returnMyResourceRouteName()` just gets the current url and `removes` the `id`